# use ros commands in bash script

Tags: ros, bash, roscd, script, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, so I need to compile my workspace every time I add it into my computer. This proves to be very time consuming. I would like to write a script that runs these commands:

```
roscd /directory/build
cmake ..
make
```

This is what I type into the terminal to compile all the directories and it works perfectly! But, when I tried just adding these commands to a script and running it I would get errors basically saying it didn't recognize the commands (i.e. `roscd`). I'm not sure if I'm supposed to source something so it will recognize the commands or something.

Any help is appreciated!
George

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185785/use-ros-commands-in-bash-script/) by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2014-07-09**:
You have a good answer down there... But, I must ask... Why are you using cmake at all? With a catkin workspace, catkin builds (invoking CMake) all packages in the source directory in topological order. This is mainly for my own curiosity.

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-07-10**:
Hey, thanks for your curiosity! When we started with ROS a catkin didn't exist. Then when it did we never made the transition, but we are planning on switching over pretty soon. Even with catkin I would like to have a script because its one less thing I need to setup when I install the system!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to source your ros workspace's startup script in your own script's instance for all of your package/stack names to be recognized by roscd.

Just add the following snippet before your commands:

> source ~/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash

Replace ros_ws with the path to your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [tgd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19648/tgd/) with karma: 76 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-09**:
Not only that, but probably he also needs to source the ROS setup script before sourcing the workspace's startup script: source /opt/ros/<your_ros_distro>/setup.bash

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-07-10**:
worked like a charm! Thanks!! @tgd

**Comment by [RDaneelOlivaw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29528/rdaneelolivaw/) on 2018-04-17**:
Mini bash script to test this:

#!/bin/bash

```
echo "Ros Test START"
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
roscd
pwd
roscd my_package
pwd
echo "Ros test END"
```